# Ektron esync - does the initial sync copy the App_GlobalResources et al files?

Tags: ektron

The Ektron documentation says:

> Regardless of how you complete the Include/ExcludeFiles field, the following siteroot folders are not synchronized:

```
App_GlobalResources
App_WebReferences
Workarea
assetlibrary
assets, privateassets, uploadedfiles, uploadedimages (individual checkboxes under Files)
latestchanges
app_webreferences
app_globalresources
```

But I guess this doesn't apply to the initial sync?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it has to ignore that exclusion for the first sync, otherwise those files wouldn't be copied in the first sync and the site wouldn't work.